# Does OpenCL allow concurrent writes to same memory address?

Tags: concurrency, shared-memory, opencl

Is two (or more) different threads allowed to write to the same memory location in global space in OpenCL? The write is always changing a uchar from 0 to 1 so the outcome should be predictable, but I'm getting erratic results in my program, so I'm wondering if the reason can be that some of the writes fail.

Could it help to declare the buffer write-only and copy it to a read-only buffer afterwards?

Comment: Most importantly, OpenCL does not support writing to `uchar` arrays (or pointers), unless you have cl_khr_byte_addressable_store extension enabled.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to be the problem (though I still don't know if simultaneous writes work, as I changed my code to do simultaneous reads instead). AFAIK I do have the extension enabled, but it doesn't seem to work... However, using uchar was not critical for me, and changing to int did the trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use the `cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics` extension and `atom_inc` intrinsic function? I would first store the data on an `int32` instead of an `uchar` as proof of concept, then optimize the memory footprint of data structures.

Comment: I circumvented the simultaneous write problem by changing my algorithm to do a simultaneous read instead. Still, it did not work until I used int instead of uchar, even though I believe I have enabled the cl_khr_byte_addressable_store extension. I'm not going to try your atomics-tip at this point though, as it seems to work well now, but thanks for the tip anyway :)