# OpenCL output buffer

Tags: opencl

I am trying to learn OpenCL basics.

I thought this code in a kernel:

```
out[ 1 & ((a+b)==(b+a)) ] = (char)1;
```

Would generate the same results as:

```
out[ 1 ] = (char)1;
```

Can anybody tell me why it generates different result?

Here is the full source code for my kernel:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
__kernel void hello(__global char * out)
{
    size_t tid = get_global_id(0);
    int a = tid & 0xff;
    int b = (tid >> 8) & 0xff;
    out[ 1 & ((a+b)==(b+a)) ] = (char)1;
}
```

If I replace that last statement with "out[1]=(char)1;" then "out[0]" will not be written. But the kernel above will write "1" to out[0].

EDIT: This is my C++ code:

```
#include <utility>
#define __NO_STD_VECTOR // Use cl::vector instead of STL version
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

inline void checkErr(cl_int err, const char * name)
{
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << name
                 << " (" << err << ")" << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cl_int err;

    cl::vector< cl::Platform > platformList;
    cl::Platform::get(&platformList);
    checkErr(platformList.size()!=0 ? CL_SUCCESS : -1, "cl::Platform::get");
    std::cerr << "Platform number is: " << platformList.size() << std::endl;

    std::string platformVendor;
    platformList[0].getInfo((cl_platform_info)CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, &platformVendor);
    std::cerr << "Platform is by: " << platformVendor << "\n";
    cl_context_properties cprops[3] = 
        {CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)(platformList[0])(), 0};

    cl::Context context(
       CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 
       cprops,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       &err);
    checkErr(err, "Conext::Context()"); 


    unsigned char outH[2] = {0};
    cl::Buffer outCL(
        context,
        CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,
        sizeof(outH),
        outH,
        &err);
    checkErr(err, "Buffer::Buffer()");


    cl::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    checkErr(
        devices.size() > 0 ? CL_SUCCESS : -1, "devices.size() > 0");


    std::ifstream file("condition1.cl");
    checkErr(file.is_open() ? CL_SUCCESS:-1, "condition1.cl");
    const std::string prog(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(prog.c_str(), prog.length()+1));
    cl::Program program(context, source);
    err = program.build(devices,""); 
    checkErr(err, "Program::build()"); 


    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "hello", &err);
    checkErr(err, "Kernel::Kernel()");

    err = kernel.setArg(0, outCL);
    checkErr(err, "Kernel::setArg()");


    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices[0], 0, &err);
    checkErr(err, "CommandQueue::CommandQueue()");


    cl::Event event;
    err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(
        kernel, 
        cl::NullRange,
        cl::NDRange(65536),
         cl::NDRange(1, 1), 
        NULL, 
        &event);
    checkErr(err, "ComamndQueue::enqueueNDRangeKernel()");

    event.wait();    
    err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(
        outCL,
        CL_TRUE,
        0,
        sizeof(outH),
        outH);
    checkErr(err, "ComamndQueue::enqueueReadBuffer()");

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(outH); i++)
        std::cout << (int)outH[i] << " ";

    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT2:

It is not caused by "undefined behaviour" at least. I get weird results for this kernel code too:

```
char result = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
        if ((a+b) != (b+a))
            result |= (1 << (a+2*b));
    }
}
```

I would expect that "result" will get the value 0. But it gets the value 6. If I change the != to an == then result gets the value 9. So in this code, when "a" is not equal with "b" then (a+b) does not equal (b+a).

If I change the code and set a known value for either "a" or "b" then the result will be 0 as I expect. For example:

```
char result = 0;
int a = 1;
/*for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++)*/ {
    for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++) {
        if ((a+b) != (b+a))
            result |= (1 << (a+2*b));
    }
}
```

Comment: The only possible explanation I can see right now is that implicitly assigning a size_t to an int might be undefined behavior, though I find that unlikely. Did you mean to use a bitwise AND in the index, though? You are only using one work unit, correct?

Comment: Thanks. yes I guess it could be because of undefined behaviour. I don't understand your "Did you intend to use a bitwise AND in the index".. because as far as I see I use it and it looks correct. I am not sure what a "work unit" is, so I added the C++ code.

Comment: I meant that since the == operator returns what would be considered a boolean, it would seem more meaningful to use the && (logical AND) operator on it. But this is a rather convoluted kernel anyway, so I guess it doesn't really matter. I will look at it again in the morning, I must get some sleep - hopefully somebody will have solved the mystery by then.

Comment: ah thanks. I also tried to write "out[((a+b)==(b+a)) ? 1 : 0] = (char)1;" but I get the same results with that.

Comment: Why are you using cl::NDRange(65536) in your kernel invocation? Is there a particular reason? (I'm more familiar with the raw C bindings than the C++ ones but I think this is the global work size parameter)

Comment: I wanted "a" and "b" to have all values from 0 to 255.

Comment: Also.. changing 65536 to a smaller value doesn't help. The for loops in my EDIT2 code will still generate bad results.

Comment: Daniel have you tried removing CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just tried that and this does not work well. If I just comment out CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR then the err is set. Perhaps you meant something different?

Comment: I can build and run the add_numbers example on DrDobbs (http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/a-gentle-introduction-to-opencl/231002854?pgno=3). And it has a condition. I intend to experiment with it.

Comment: When I experiment with the DrDobbs example code I get unexpected behaviour too. So for me it seems the problem is not only in my initial C++ code but in the DrDobbs C code as well.

Comment: @DanielMarjamäki: is it normal that global and local work sizes have different dimensions in `enqueueNDRangeKernel` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861401/does-opencl-allow-concurrent-writes-to-same-memory-address. It looks your `uchar` datatype could be the problem (even though you have the extension enabled)